# Android Cursor Query Count

Tags: android, sql, count, android-cursor

I'm developing a small application that reads data from a database and displys it in a few custom listview layouts.

I got all my ducks in a row but have one issue where I can't wrap my mind around which is preforming a count within the cursor query

Here is a simple example of my code

```
private static final String fields[] = { "CarYear","CarMake","CarModel","CarInfo", BaseColumns._ID }; //BaseColumns._ID
```

And the query itself

```
                Cursor data = database.query("Car060", fields, null, null, null, null,null);
```

So the big question is how can I either preform a total count per maker or just a total count.

Thanks for any assistance

Ended up using a RawQuery

Cursor Count = database.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT People) as NumberOfPeople FROM WhatEverDB", null);

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [Cursor.getCount()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getCount%28%29) to get the total number of rows returned by the cursor.

To count individual 'makers' you can either iterate over the cursor, and count them yourself, or use another query to issue COUNT SQL to the server and retrieve the counts from there.

As you're already fetching this data for use in a ListView, I'd *guess* that the former is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution would be to use a query that groups by maker.

Comment: Hi Philip, I'm trying to get a listview with two values list of CarMakers on the left and Count of cars based on CarMakers on the Right, I know how to do this with a rawQuery but i'm not able to populate the listView from a rawQuery... do you have an example maybe? I've searched and searched but can't find any solution that would work for me